# Local WideString variable debug error "Int3 DbgBreakPoint"

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder, widestring

In C++Builder, I wrote the following code (in Button1Click handler), When I run in debug mode, I get the "Int3 DbgBreakPoint" (Stack corrupted?). This doesn't happen for AnsiSting (Maybe reference counting).

```
WideString boshluq;
boshluq=L" ";
```

Is this normal? What do you suggest me to fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WideStrings are pointer referenced variables for Windows WideStrings, maybe the problem is in your windows system library.

I have the same problem with breakpoint in the ntdll.dll, I dont know if it is the same for you.

I solve with this unit http://www.tbosystems.bluehosting.com.br/dbx4/int3.pas (Thanks to Leonel Togniolli), maybe you can check this out and see if can help you out, or try the same code in other windows machine.

Comment: Yes you are right. It solved my problem. Thanks a lot. And thanks to Leonel Togniolli.

Answer (score 1):

Or a debug version of a library getting called with WideStrings? With an explicit int 3; call build in?

Comment: I tried this code (two lines) in C++Builder 6 and C++Builder 2006. Same result. I don't believe that they both have int3 in their library.

Comment: It could be that they both call the same win32 api function which has it.